# Java JDK installation per cmd on Windows machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, java

How can I install a JDK via cmd or with another file?
I have to reset my Windows PC regularly for security reasons and I don't always want to go through the setup menu.

A Batch or CMD file to install any JDK, the JDK Version 19 is needed.

Comment: Use winget: https://adoptium.net/installation/ ?

Comment: By the way, Java 19 is now end-of-life. I suggest you use either the latest (version 20), or one of the long-term support versions (8, 11, 17, and likely 21).

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions of (desktop) Windows (i.e. current versions of Windows 11) come with Microsoft's package manager [*Windows Package Manager*](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/package-manager/) pre-installed which includes the [`winget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/package-manager/winget/) command line tool. If your version of Windows does not have `winget` pre-installed, you can install the Windows Package Manager from the [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/) as part of the [*App Installer* package](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/app-installer/9NBLGGH4NNS1). Installation packages are also available on the [project page on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli).

Windows Package Manager supports Windows 10 1809 and up, i.e. all Windows client versions of the last 5 years (but not Windows Server).

Windows Package Manager uses so-called [*repositories*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository) to find the packages to install. The two repositories which are configured by default are the *msstore* repository (which lets you install any package from the Microsoft Store) and the [*winget* repository](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs) (a community-curated repository of packages which are not available in the Microsoft Store). You can also add [third-party repositories](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/blob/master/THIRD_PARTY.md) but like with any package manager, it is your responsibility to correctly asses how much trust you want to place into the curator(s) of those repositories.

[Packages for Oracle Java SE JDK are available in the *winget* repository](https://winget.run/pkg/Oracle/JDK.19) and can be [installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/package-manager/winget/install) like this:

```powershell
winget install --exact --id Oracle.JDK.19
```

Currently, [the *winget* repository contains no fewer than 65 different JDK packages](https://winget.run/search?query=jdk) for any of your Java development needs.